# How to get line number in multi-line textbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on asp.net based application. I am using multi-line textbox and I am using java script in asp.net.I want to find a line number of a particular character or text in a multi-line textbox. How can I get line number from a multi-line textbox using Javascript?

Comment: I can give you this in Jquery if you want

Comment: you have any idea about java script?

Comment: @Praveen: Just edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8984260/284240) to add a js-way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] lines = Textbox1.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
int lineNumberOfText = -1;
for (int lineNumber = 0; lineNumber <= lines.Length - 1; lineNumber++) {
    if (lines(lineNumber).Contains(textToSearch)) {
        lineNumberOfText = lineNumber;
        break; 
    }
}
```

**Edit**: You just changed the title from ASP.NET to javascript, so this answer is incorrect but might be helpful anyhow.

Here's a **Javascript** function that does what you want(with the option of case-insitive search):

```
function getLineNumber(id, text, caseSensitive) {
    var input = document.getElementById(id);
    if (input != null) {
        caseSensitive = (caseSensitive == true || caseSensitive == "true") ? true : false;
        if (!caseSensitive) text = text.toLowerCase();
        var lines = input.value.split('\n');
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            var line = caseSensitive ? lines[i] : lines[i].toLowerCase();
            if (line.indexOf(text) != -1) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Following would print out the first line number that contains "Hello World"(case-insensitive) `alert(getLineNumber('Textarea1','Hello World',false))`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in following manner in C# code

```
yourInputString
// Get the text before your particular text
.Substring(0, yourInputString.IndexOf("ParticularText"))
// Get all lines
.Split('\n')
.Length
```

**UPDATE:** As you have mentioned in comment, you want to do this in javascript, here it goes

```
textBoxName.Value
// Get the text before your particular text
.substring(0, textBoxName.Value.indexOf("ParticularText"))
// Get all lines
.split('\n')
.length
```

Comment: how can i add this to java script?

Comment: You have not mentioned javascript in question?

Answer (score 0):

Praveen, I have tried something with `HTML` here http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/Uk6td/2/. But it is not fool-proof. Because if you have 50 characters in a row (like we have in example) but the a word is more than 50 characters long it will break all logic. Also if a word does not fits in a row it is moved to next row and column index breaks. It will give you rough idea about row but very erroneous in case of column after first row.